# In D&D 5e, do most wands no longer require command words?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In the section on magic items in the DMG, under Activating a Magic Item, it states:

> Activating some magic items requires a user to do something in
> particular, such as holding the item and uttering a command word,
> reading the item if it is a scroll, or drinking it if it is a potion.
> The description of each item category or individual item details how
> an item is activated.

Further down, under Spells in the same section, it states:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often
> by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible
> spell and caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots,
> and ***requires no components*** [emphasis mine] unless the item’s description says
> otherwise.

Note this emphasized text does not say ***material*** components, just components. That would suggest verbal and somatic components as well as material.

The general description of wands says nothing about command words, either:

> A magic wand is about 15 inches long and crafted of metal, bone, or
> wood. It is tipped with metal, crystal, stone, or some other material.

Further, some wand descriptions specifically mention a command word. For example, the wand of enemy detection says:

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action and
> expend 1 charge to ***speak its command word*** [emphasis mine]. For the next minute, you
> know the direction of the nearest creature hostile to you . . .

So going by the tenet that in 5e, the specific overrides the general, all this would suggest wands no longer need a command word to function, unless otherwise stated. But this seems like a really strange change to make from previous editions, and I've scoured both the rest of the rules and the web to see if I missed something.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a question about how wands work, or simply looking for someone to do a manual count of each published wand, whether or not they are activated by a word or not, and then comparing the have/have nots.

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information..

Comment: I wasn't hoping for someone else to check all the wands; I merely wanted to make sure I hadn't missed information elsewhere in the rules that confirmed or conflicted with my reasoning. Again, wands not having command words is unusual compared to previous editions of the rules, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I'm still unsure as to your reasoning/question. Are you just asking for confirmation that most wands in 5e don't require activation words?

Comment: My question was, is there something written elsewhere than what I've quoted that clarifies/contradicts my reasoning? Is there some podcast where Jeremy Crawford addressed this issue that I am unaware of? The answer appears to be no.

Comment: What reasoning are you talking about? Are you asking if your reasoning is *why* there is no activation words on wands? If so, that's going to be closed as a [designer-intent](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic) which are off-topic because speculation often comes into play. It's also been restated by WoTC that Crawford's statements are no longer official.

Comment: @TSRThomas They just decided to change it, and they maybe goofed up and left one wand with a command word.

Comment: @NautArch, by "reasoning," I just mean, "based on what I have found to date in the RAW, it appears wands by default no longer require command words. In other words, I have reasoned out that wands no longer require these based on all the block-quoted sections I listed in the original post. Is that reasoning sound? The answer clearly is yes.

Comment: @TSRThomas I’m no longer sure what you’re asking here. I’m voting to close until there is further clarity. In the question you just seem to be asking if you have observed correctly that most wands don’t require activation words, but in comments you seem to be asking why this is the case.

Comment: I’m not sure how else to phrase this. My question was, “Do wands not require command words in 5e?” Based on what I have found THUS FAR in the rules, that seems to be the case, but that seems odd to me because wands always had a command word in previous editions, so I am asking if I missed something. Everyone’s answer has been, “You are correct, wands do not require command words in 5e. You did not miss some snippet of rules elsewhere that contradicts what you concluded.”

Comment: TSRThomas, I think the difference is in "Do wants not require command words in 5e", which has been answered. But your question and comments seem to suggest you are asking "It seems like wands don't require command words in 5e. Is this reasoning accurate as to why?" The latter is not something we can answer, but the former is.

Comment: I get what you are saying, @NautArch, and I understand why you thought that. But that's not what I was ultimately asking. I was asking for someone to confirm what I had concluded based on what I had found or point me to other information that would disabuse me of that notion. There is no other information, so the answer is, "No, 5e wands do not require command words." The question has been answered and I am satisfied. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The wand's description tells us how to use it.

This is clear from the rules you quoted:

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item, often by expending charges from it. The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell and caster level, doesn’t expend any of the user’s spell slots, and requires no components unless the item’s description says otherwise.

Presently, *only one* wand in D&D 5e material requires a command word for activation, the [Wand of Enemy Detection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-enemy-detection):

> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action and expend 1 charge to speak its command word.

This is the only wand that explicitly requires activation via a command word. This is confirmed by observing [this search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=wand%20command&f=equipment,magic-items&c=items) at DnDBeyond.

Every other wand says something like:

> you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges.

As David Coffron noted in the comments, the rules make no special provisions for wands with respect to command words, so these wands do not require use of a command word to activate.

*This covers all official D&D 5e material.*

Comment: It is clear from what I posted. What I wanted to make sure of was that there was no other information that contradicted this elsewhere in the rules, i.e., a specific statement that contradicts what I've reasoned out. I'm asking because it's very different from previous editions of the rules.

Comment: @TSRThomas This answer is saying there isn't any specific rules; and I, at least, concur (+1).

Comment: You could add that the [chapter on Magic Items in the *Basic Rules*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#CommandWord) makes no special rules for wands. Also, the [rules for command words](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#CommandWord) make no special delegation regarding wands either.

Comment: @TSRThomas Yep, am a D&D and AD&D vet from way back; the lack of command words struck me as well in this edition.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it doesn't sound like anyone knows of other information that would contradict what I have cited, so the answer does indeed seem to be, wands no longer require command words unless otherwise noted in their descriptions. Thanks for all the responses, everyone.

Comment: The *wand of fear* also specifically says "use an action to expend 1 charge and command a creature..." so that one is gonna have a verbal component, in the form of the command you give, if you count that as an activation word.  The fear cone effect (and several other wand effects) emit from the wand's tip, so being able to point them is necessary in those cases. (And of course the DM can decide any given wand has a command word or other usage requirement.)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I assume you mean the [Wand of Fear](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-fear)? That one is entirely incidental to the fact that the magical effect is basically the spell *command*. *Technically*, activating the wand to cast the spell does not require a command word, but the spell being cast does. If the wand itself required a command word to activate, then it would require *two* command words to properly use.

Comment: Geez, I fixed my post in under a minute to name the item correctly. Anyway -- there's no such thing as "two command words", it either requires speaking to use or it doesn't. It doesn't matter if the "command word" is one word or a full paragraph of elvish.